# In Typescript, error constructing Map<string,T> from Array<T> using common string field for key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

The following code in Typescript gives an assignment error on the last line

```
interface T {id: string}
let ts: Array<T> = []
let tMap: Map<string, T> =
    new Map (
        ts.map(t => [t.id, t])
    )
```

Similar code in a javascript environment works. Cant see what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Typescript can't infer the the map content as tuples, which should probably be reported as a bug. But I found a workaround which I think is acceptable, by explicitly writing the type of the map content:

```
let tMap: Map<string, T> =
  new Map(ts.map<[string, T]>(t => [t.id, t]))
```

Comment: Thank you. Clearly tuples are second class citizens compared to union types. As you suggest, there seems to be enough information to have inferred the tuple type, so I agree, it looks like a buglet. Your casting suggestion does the trick neatly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Map` constructor wants an array of two-element [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), but TypeScript [does not infer tuple types from string literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3369).  That means, the following:

```
const foo = [1, "two"];
```

is inferred as the array type `Array<string | number>` and *not* the tuple type `[number, string]`.  If you want it to be `[number, string]` you can use an explicit type annotation like

```
const foo: [number, string] = [1, "two"];
```

or a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like

```
const foo = [1, "two"] as [number, string];
```

Or, if you need this a lot, since it *is* possible to get TypeScript to [infer a tuple type from function arguments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), you can make a helper function like this:

```
const tuple = <T extends any[]>(...t: T) => t;
```

and then use it:

```
const foo = tuple(1, "two"); // inferred as type [number, string]
```

---

Any of those will help you get `[t.id, t]` to behave properly.  Let's try the last one:

```
interface T { id: string }
let ts: Array<T> = []
let tMap: Map<string, T> =
  new Map(
    ts.map(t => tuple(t.id, t))  // okay 
  );
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think I slightly prefer @ShamPooSham's work around.